# Getting column name from table with single quote

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have table with 'tableColumn' column and 'tableColumn' column  has BS:Infra value.

Now i want BS:Infra value in single quote in select statement

How can i do in following statement

select tableColumn from table

Answer (score 0):

```
select CONCAT('''', tableColumn, '''') from table;
```

Comment: I am getting BS: Cash value from table and i want this in sinqle qoute with listagg function in 
 below statment SELECT LISTAGG( CONCAT('''', tableColumn, ''''),',') AS pivotcolumnList FROM table

Answer (score 0):

What Marcel suggested works for me:

```
create or replace table test (c1 string);
insert into test values ('BS:Infra');
insert into test values ('BS:Test');

SELECT 
  LISTAGG( CONCAT('''', c1, ''''),',') AS pivotcolumnList 
FROM test;

+----------------------+
| PIVOTCOLUMNLIST      |
|----------------------|
| 'BS:Infra','BS:Test' |
+----------------------+
```

Isn't this what you want?